# How to make text vertically aligned in D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

I am trying to make d3.js tree text as vertically aligned, because I am having almost 50 child nodes in my tree because of which all text are getting overlapped. I don't wanna change my tree orientation.

Comment: Any code to show us what you got so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "vertically aligned"? Do you want to change the orientation of the text?